# Resource for practicing sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, summation, book-recommendation

Frequently I come across a sum (either finite or infinite, and often in the context of moments of discrete random variables) and unless I can force it into one of the few forms that I know, such as a geometric series, sum of a known probability mass function, or a known Taylor series, I am stumped. I feel that my lack of skill with the machinery of summation is holding me back.

Are there any good resources out there, either free or not, containing a large number of worked examples? I'm aware of such resources for calculus/integration, such as [Schaum's 3000 solved problems in calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635343), but I haven't seen any for sums.

Comment: There's a very similar book called Schaum's Calculus Sixth Edition with many series and sequence problems.

Comment: I haven't seen any resources focusing solely on sums, but here are some of my blog posts with lots of sum problems that you may find helpful: http://nilknarf.langlab.org/entries/2017-6-9.html, http://nilknarf.langlab.org/entries/2017-6-24.html

Comment: @BenjaminMoss ok, good to know!

Comment: @Nilknark thank you for the link, that looks very helpful indeed